# Mongo connector unable to connect to mongos

Tags: mongodb, connector

I am connecting to mongo with a user with clusterAdmin and backup roles, but I get the error:

```
2017-02-09 17:51:23,254 [ERROR] mongo_connector.util:96 - Fatal Exception
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mongo_connector/util.py", line 94, in wrapped
    func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mongo_connector/connector.py", line 370, in run
    'listShards')['shards']:
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mongo_connector/util.py", line 78, in retry_until_ok
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/pymongo/database.py", line 494, in command
    codec_options, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/pymongo/database.py", line 406, in _command
    parse_write_concern_error=parse_write_concern_error)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/pymongo/pool.py", line 419, in command
    collation=collation)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/pymongo/network.py", line 116, in command
    parse_write_concern_error=parse_write_concern_error)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/pymongo/helpers.py", line 210, in _check_command_response
    raise OperationFailure(msg % errmsg, code, response)
OperationFailure: not authorized on admin to execute command { listShards: 1 }
```

This page under Required Permissions says The simplest way to get mongo-connector running is to create a user with the backup role:

https://github.com/mongodb-labs/mongo-connector/wiki/Usage-with-Authentication

```
db.getSiblingDB("admin").createUser({ user:"backup",pwd:"password_here", roles: ["backup"] })
```

But I cant even connect with such a user (Authentication error):

```
2017-02-10 16:52:01,448 [ERROR] mongo_connector.util:96 - Fatal Exception
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mongo_connector/util.py", line 94, in wrapped
    func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mongo_connector/connector.py", line 398, in run
    hosts, replicaSet=repl_set)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mongo_connector/connector.py", line 299, in create_authed_client
    client['admin'].authenticate(self.auth_username, self.auth_key)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/pymongo/database.py", line 1048, in authenticate
    connect=True)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/pymongo/mongo_client.py", line 505, in _cache_credentials
    sock_info.authenticate(credentials)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/pymongo/pool.py", line 523, in authenticate
    auth.authenticate(credentials, self)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/pymongo/auth.py", line 470, in authenticate
    auth_func(credentials, sock_info)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/pymongo/auth.py", line 450, in _authenticate_default
    return _authenticate_scram_sha1(credentials, sock_info)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/pymongo/auth.py", line 201, in _authenticate_scram_sha1
    res = sock_info.command(source, cmd)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/pymongo/pool.py", line 419, in command
    collation=collation)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/pymongo/network.py", line 116, in command
    parse_write_concern_error=parse_write_concern_error)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/pymongo/helpers.py", line 210, in _check_command_response
    raise OperationFailure(msg % errmsg, code, response)
OperationFailure: Authentication failed.
```

When I log into mongos with both these users and run the command

```
db.getSiblingDB("admin").runCommand( { listShards: 1 } )
```

I get a shard listing no probs

```
 {
        "shards" : [
                {
                        "_id" : "shard001",
                        "host" : "shard001/timgrhlmdb01:27020,timgrhlmdb02:27020",
                        "state" : 1
                },
                {
                        "_id" : "shard002",
                        "host" : "shard002/timgrhlmdb03:27020,timgrhlmdb04:27020",
                        "state" : 1
                }
        ],
        "ok" : 1
}
```

So what does this mean:

**OperationFailure: not authorized on admin to execute command { listShards: 1 }**

Update

I rebuilt the cluster from scratch and still have the same problem:  **OperationFailure: not authorized on admin to execute command { listShards: 1 }**

I have also tried the user 'backup' with only the roles 'clusterManager' and 'readAnyDatabase'. This allows the user to list shards, but now mongo-connector fails with 'Authentication failed':

```
{ "_id" : "admin.backup", "user" : "backup", "db" : "admin", "credentials" : { "SCRAM-SHA-1" : { "iterationCount" : 10000, "salt" : "pWcEU7uFqfHPgGe8z+E9Wg==", "storedKey" : "k2tapXQPtM2dHlxYnJiWVxO/rtg=", "serverKey" : "EGG8M4i27OYBy+fLYaL13+Nn4mc=" } }, "roles" : [ { "role" : "readAnyDatabase", "db" : "admin" }, { "role" : "clusterManager", "db" : "admin" } ] }
```

Comment: on a side note, the mongo documentation contains errors https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/deploy-sharded-cluster-with-keyfile-access-control/ says to create the shard replica sets on the config server. also initialising a replica set wont work unless the id is in quotes.

Comment: bug submitted https://github.com/mongodb-labs/mongo-connector/issues/662

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Response from bug submitted to mongodb-labs/mongo-connector:

> This is indeed a subtle bug introduced in #563. We changed a find on
>   config.shards into a call to listShards assuming that it would have no
>   change in behavior. Unfortunately (and annoyingly), the backup role
>   has privileges to read the list of shards in the config.shards
>   collection but, as you can see, does not have the privilege to run the
>   listShards command. I'll revert this change to **fix the problem in
>   the upcoming 2.5.1 bug-fix release**.
>
> In the meantime, you will need to grant the mongo-connector user the
>   **backup AND clusterMonitor** roles.
>
> An important point that is not yet mentioned in the documentation is
>   that the **user must be created on a mongos and all the shards**. This
>   enables mongo-connector to authenticate to the cluster as a whole and
>   to each shard individually.

This now works! yay

That will teach me for following the manual lol!

Answer (score 0):

Check out users by running this command:

```
db.system.users.find({})
```

Make sure that the user you created is with a `backup` role,if you can log in as the **backup** user and you can also run those commands,that means **backup** user was created and granted a role and its privileges.

---

Make sure that you have the role of `clusterManager` to perform this.

> Provides management and monitoring actions on the cluster. A user with
>   this role can access the config and local databases, which are used in
>   sharding and replication, respectively.
>
> Provides the following actions on the cluster as a whole:
>
> - addShard
> - appendOplogNote
> - applicationMessage
> - cleanupOrphaned
> - flushRouterConfig
> - **listShards**
> - removeShard
>     etc

Have a look at [built-in-roles](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/built-in-roles/#clusterManager).

By the way,have a look at this [issue](https://github.com/mongodb-labs/mongo-connector/issues/626).Hope this helps.

Comment: I created my cluster again from scratch but I still get this same error. If I auth as admin and run db.system.users.find({}) it shows the user 'backup' with the role 'backup' on database 'admin'. if I run db.runCommand("listShards") it gives the Unauthorized message. Sooo the backup role cannot list shards???

Comment: if i add the role 'root' to the user 'backup', I can now list shards, but the connector fails with Authentication failed..

Comment: @stackoverflows It seems that you should have the role of `clusterManager` to perform this. Have a look at [built-in-roles](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/built-in-roles/#clusterManager)